# Connect to local server from Matlab

Tags: c++, qt, matlab, localserver

I want to communicate back and forth between a Matlab script and a Qt (C++) app on the same machine.  In Qt, you create a `QLocalServer` object and direct it to listen for connections on a specific handle, like 'my_server' (can be anything).

In Matlab, I've looked at what seem like the relevant MatlabCentral listings, such as [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24525-a-simple-udp-communications-application) and [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21131-tcpip-socket-communications-in-matlab), but in neither case can I get them to work, and I don't even see how to do this--there is no ability to specify a handle.  If I just tell them to listen to local host, they don't connect.

So what can I do here?  Doing this through a MEX file is probably possible but I'm leaving that as a last resort.  Also I'm stuck with R2009b so I don't have the `udp` command in Matlab.

Comment: Consider using Java Sockets: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25249-tcpip-socket-communications-in-matlab-using-java-classes

Comment: @slayton That is basically identical to the second listing I mentioned.  Same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that Qt's `QLocalServer`/`QLocalSocket` are not the right classes for doing this, despite their names.  Rather, the MatlabCentral files I referenced (and probably also the one @Frederik mentioned, although I could not immediately get that to work) do just fine if you create a `QTcpServer` and corresponding `QTcpSocket`, and set, on both ends, host to localhost and port to 4444 (or whatever).  I found it very easy to build what I needed following Qt's [Loopback example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/main-snapshot/network-loopback.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try the Toolbox from Peter Rydesäter: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/345-tcpudpip-toolbox-2-0-6 quite old but still works.

Example with two Matlab-Instances:

Sender:

```
function sendudp(host, port, data)
  udp=pnet('udpsocket',1111);          % open local socket on port 1111
  pnet(udp,'write',data);              % write data to buffer
  pnet(udp,'writepacket',host,port);   % send udp-packet
  pnet(udp,'close');                   % close connection
end
```

Receiver:

```
sock = pnet('udpsocket', 950) % open socket on port 950
```

Sender:

```
sendudp('127.0.0.1', 950, 'Hello World') % Call function defined above, send Hello World to localhost, port 950
```

Receiver:

```
size = pnet(sock, 'readpacket'); % Get Data from sock, and load to buffer
data = pnet(sock, 'read'); % Read Data from buffer
```

Comment: Right I've looked at that but it's the same story--how do I specify a handle?  You can input an IP address or 'localhost' only as far as I can tell.  But I don't know how to connect to my other process specifically.